# JSON.parse() Chrome/Firefox differences

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, google-chrome, firefox

I met a very little strange problem about the return error of JSON.parse() function:
I use this function to validate JSON string that i retrieve from a web based editor. That string is pre-manipulated using JSON.stringify() function.
more precisely:

`JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)`

So, when I use Firefox (v107.0.1), in case of malformed string, I can display the line number and the column number of the typo, but when I use Chrome (v 107.0.5304.87) lines are not recognized.

I assume that is a JS engine problem but I was wondering if there is a way to fix the problem.

Thanks

- test with different browsers versions
- change string format

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your issue here is, if the JSON was created with `JSON.stringify`, it should be next to impossible for `JSON.parse` to fail.  Do you have any examples of this happening..?

Comment: @Keith I use JSON.stringify only for pretty viewing json string in code editor, I use JSON.parse to validate the string after editing so the exception is only raised on error after string modification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions between browsers are likely implementation specific.

But if you do want a more robust JSON parser, you could use JSON5, with this line numbers etc, should be consistent between browsers.

eg..

```js
console.log('Incorrect JSON');
//with error
try {
  var a = JSON5.parse(`
  {
    hello: 'there'x
  }`);
  console.log(a);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('JSON error at', e.lineNumber, e.columnNumber);
}

console.log('Valid JSON');
//corrected
try {
  var a = JSON5.parse(`
  {
    hello: 'there'
  }`);
  console.log(a);
} catch (e) {
  console.log('JSON error at', e.lineNumber, e.columnNumber);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/json5@^2.0.0/dist/index.min.js"></script>
```